# Dell U2711 Flat Panel Monitor

Tags: mac

I have a Dell U2711 Flat Panel Monitor, which I have been using with my Mac, preIntel and Intel. Suddenly I cannot acces to any control, instead a padlock appears on my screen. Any help?

Comment: This is a display issue

Answer (score 1):

Press and hold the two bottom buttons (4+5) for 15 seconds. The lock symbol will "unlock" after 15 seconds and you should be able to use the OSD menu again.

Comment: it worked. life is a lot easier thanks to people like you.

Comment: Thanks, @FranciscoBatallerAlvarez. Feel free to mark my answer as accepted. :)